# Regex JS - Create Capture Pattern Without Specified Word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture with Javascript regex any string between my domain and `.html` (if present), but am having trouble doing so. Any advice?

```
Regex:
www\.mysite\.com\/(.*)(\.html)    // Does not capture 'www.mysite.com/cat'
www\.mysite\.com\/(.*)(\.html)?   // Captures the '.html'

Test Data:
www.mysite.com/aadvark.html      (capture group should be 'aadvark')
www.mysite.com/bird.html         (capture group should be 'bird')
www.mysite.com/cat               (capture group should be 'cat')
```

Comment: or maybe `(.*?)` to lazy match instead of greedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of issues like this can be fixed by being more specific with your dot-match-all. If you change your `.*` to `[^.]*` (0+ non-`.` characters), you'll get your expected results.

```
/www\.mysite\.com\/([^.]*)(\.html)?/
```

This is because when you make `(\.html)` optional, the `.*` greedily continues to the end. This could also be fixed by using `?` to make your repetition "lazy" (stops as soon as the next part of the expression matches); however, then you'd need to anchor the end of the expression with a `$`.

```
/www\.mysite\.com\/(.*?)(\.html)?$/
```

---

I'd recommend this first. But, the second is more encompassing by matching things like `foo.bar` in `www.mysite.com/foo.bar.html`.